# When did Bitcoin's "To The Moon" meme begin?

Tags: market, community

When did Bitcoin's "To The Moon" meme begin, and where did it originate?

Comment: related: [ToTheMoonGuy.com](http://tothemoonguy.com/pages/about) ;)